# What is the best way to build multi-language app with react and redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, internationalization, react-router, multilingual

I'm starting a new react.js project and it requires two language support. The app will have a lot of text in both the UI and data coming from the server.

My question is how to, first: switch between the UI language, second: based on the UI switcher fetch the translated data?

Do I do that via Redux where I change the data in the store and all the reducers based on the language that the user chose?

What is the best way to go about accomplishing this successfully and easily as it's my first time implementing a multi-language app with React?

Comment: The question is way too broad...

Comment: @SakoBu I need some kind of workflow guidelines on how to approach such a project? Is there any kind of a package that can facilitate the process?

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the translations in redux. Store them in a config file and only the language setting in Redux. In your components, connect to redux, pass the language through mapStateToProps and in your render() methods, get the text from the config.

For example:

```
import config from './config';

//////////

render() {
  const { language } = this.props;

  return <Text>{config.menuButton[language]}</Text>
}
```

Comment: So do you mean I store the UI translation into .JSON file?

Comment: Exactly. Store in a JSON file.